# Typing a Promise in Typescript 2.0

Tags: angularjs, typescript

The following compiled and worked fine in Typescript 1.8 and Angular 1. Now our development platform is moving to Typescript 2.3. The same function fails to compile in Typescript 2.3 at the return statement:

"Type 'IPromise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'IPromise'"

How do you type a Promise? Is there a cast?

```
detail(id: string): ng.IPromise<IInvOrder> {
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http.get(this.apiUrl + "/Detail/" + id)
        .success((result: IInvOrder) => defer.resolve(result))
        .error((err: any) => defer.reject(err));
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Does using `return (defer.promise as ng.IPromise<IInvOrder>);` fix the typing error?

Comment: Did not try this. I took the solution below as cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fix

TypeScript now forces you to use explicit generics when they cannot be inferred.

## Example

Change `var defer = this.$q.defer();` to `var defer = this.$q.defer<IInvOrder();`

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thanks!